# How to generate distinct pairs in R?

Tags: r

If given a vector, for instance:

```r
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

How do I generate the distinct pairs i.e. (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)?

and more generally is there a way to create n-length "pairs", for instance:

(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5)
or
(1,2,3,4), (2,3,4,5)

I have tried the function `combn`, but this gives me all kinds of permutations where as I only want the distinct ones (i, i+1).
The output does not really matter. A `data.frame` could be fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See also: [Create a rolling list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137750/create-a-rolling-list-in-r)

Comment: [Lagging time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67035286/lagging-time-series-data)

Answer (score 3):

This might do:

```r
get_subsets <- function(x, n_ele){
  if(length(x) < n_ele)
    return(matrix(vector(typeof(x), 0L), n_ele, 0L))
  matrix(x[outer(seq_len(n_ele) - 1L, seq_len(length(x) - n_ele + 1L), `+`)], 
         n_ele)
}

# use the function on the example provided by the OP
x <- 1:5
get_subsets(x, 2L)
#R>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#R> [1,]    1    2    3    4
#R> [2,]    2    3    4    5
get_subsets(x, 3L)
#R>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#R> [1,]    1    2    3
#R> [2,]    2    3    4
#R> [3,]    3    4    5
get_subsets(x, 4L)
#R>      [,1] [,2]
#R> [1,]    1    2
#R> [2,]    2    3
#R> [3,]    3    4
#R> [4,]    4    5
get_subsets(x, 5L)
#R>      [,1]
#R> [1,]    1
#R> [2,]    2
#R> [3,]    3
#R> [4,]    4
#R> [5,]    5
get_subsets(x, 6L)
#R>     
#R> [1,]
#R> [2,]
#R> [3,]
#R> [4,]
#R> [5,]
#R> [6,]
```

Calling the function `get_subsets` is perhaps not the best idea.

> How do I generate the distinct pairs i.e. (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)?

These are not really "distinct pairs" but rather sub sequences of continuous elements?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** : `combn` tweeked is an answer :

```r
straight_flush <- function(.x, .m){
    
    dfr <- as.data.frame(t(combn(x = .x, m = .m)))
    
    return( dfr[!duplicated(dfr$V1) , ] )
    
}

straight_flush(.x = 1:20, .m = 2)
#>     V1 V2
#> 1    1  2
#> 20   2  3
#> 38   3  4
#> 55   4  5
#> 71   5  6
#> 86   6  7
#> 100  7  8
#> 113  8  9
#> 125  9 10
#> 136 10 11
#> 146 11 12
#> 155 12 13
#> 163 13 14
#> 170 14 15
#> 176 15 16
#> 181 16 17
#> 185 17 18
#> 188 18 19
#> 190 19 20
straight_flush(.x = 1:20, .m = 3)
#>      V1 V2 V3
#> 1     1  2  3
#> 172   2  3  4
#> 325   3  4  5
#> 461   4  5  6
#> 581   5  6  7
#> 686   6  7  8
#> 777   7  8  9
#> 855   8  9 10
#> 921   9 10 11
#> 976  10 11 12
#> 1021 11 12 13
#> 1057 12 13 14
#> 1085 13 14 15
#> 1106 14 15 16
#> 1121 15 16 17
#> 1131 16 17 18
#> 1137 17 18 19
#> 1140 18 19 20
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `embed`:

```
n = 2
embed(embed(vec, length(vec) - n + 1)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    4    3    2    1
# [2,]    5    4    3    2

n = 4
embed(vec, length(vec) - n + 1)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    1
# [2,]    3    2
# [3,]    4    3
# [4,]    5    4
```

---

You may fill a matrix, where one dimension (e.g. `nrow`) is "oversized" by 1. Then select an appropriate subset.

```
f = function(vec, n){
len = length(vec)
matrix(vec, nrow = len + 1, ncol = len)[1:(len - n + 1), 1:n]
}

f(vec, 2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    2    3
# [3,]    3    4
# [4,]    4    5

f(vec, 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    2    3    4
# [3,]    3    4    5
```

Comment: @Esben77 Please note that I added an `embed` alternative.